# How can I set the idle timer for a disk connected to a 3ware RAID controller?

Tags: linux, power-management, 3ware

I have Linux server with a 3ware 9550SX SATA RAID controller with several disks attached. One of them is a 2TB disk that I'm using for backups. It's a normal desktop disk (i.e. not for 24/7) and I want that disk to spin down when it's idle for 20 minutes. Unfortunately, `hdparm -S 240` on the device gives me `HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(setidl1) failed: Invalid argument.`

Is there another way to spin down the drive or do I really have to walk down in the cellar, delete the unit, pull it out of the bay, after every incremental backup?

Comment: what does `hdparm -C` tell you?  what mfg/model is the drive?

Comment: It says "drive state is: unknown". -i/-I also give errors. I can test the drive with -t but that probably doesn't use any low-level commands.

Comment: Ancient question, voting to close.

Comment: Why? The question is still relevant.

Comment: I did this with quite a few questions with zero votes and zero answers. Mostly to remove a bit of SU clutter. Your comment should keep it from getting any more votes so it is in no danger of being closed.  As it is still relevant may I suggest that you edit the question and perhaps add a little more info. That will bump the question to the Active question front page and you'll have a greater chance of getting an answer. Another way to attract attention would be to add a bounty on the question.

Comment: Is it possible to set a different timeout value on each disk of each (raid) pair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a new enough 3ware firmware and smartctl, you can set the drive standby timeout like this (port #5 in this exmaple);

```
smartctl -d 3ware,5 -s standby,7 /dev/twa0
```

The 7 is the timeout, see the description of the "hdparm -s" option for a description of what the values mean.

Current firmwares handle spun down drives correct and will not accidentally spin them up or kick them out.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that ASAP. And shouldn't that be `hdparm -S` (upper case)?